# AS3 and PHP echo SHA256 issue

Tags: php, actionscript-3

I am having a small issue with the hash function of PHP.
The PHP code works fine when run on it's own (the .php file) but when I try to return the results in Flash CC I get the following error:

( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'hash' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\wamp\www\sha256.php on line *2*

My Code:
AS3:

```
import flash.events.Event;

function submitted():void{
var myrequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://localhost/sha256.php");
myrequest.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;

var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, dataOnLoad);
loader.load(myrequest);
}
function dataOnLoad(e:Event):void{

    result.text = e.target.data.toString();
}

submitted();
```

PHP:

```
<?php
echo hash("sha256", "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.");
?>
```

As I said, when viewing the php file directly from the browser I get the correct response (68b1282b91de2c054c36629cb8dd447f12f096d3e3c587978dc2248444633483), but through Flash I get that error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: can you check it without hash first, just use `echo "test"` for example

Comment: Yes echo works. I have fixed my code, see below. It works now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Never mind guys,
I got it fixed.

In case anyone else has the same problem this is my code:
AS3:

```
import flash.events.Event;

var myrequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://localhost/sha256.php");
myrequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();

var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

function submitted(r:String):void
{
    variables.data = r;
    myrequest.data = variables;
    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, dataOnLoad);
    loader.load(myrequest);
}


function dataOnLoad(e:Event):void
{
    result.text = e.target.data.toString();
}

submitted("My String");
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$res = $_POST["data"];
echo hash("sha256", $res);
?>
```